JOptionPane drop down menu doesn't show any values
I am trying to make a Map that will map a dogs name to the dog object, it then prints out the list of available dogs and should show a drop down menu asking the user to select from one of the above dogs.
This is the code I have been using. The drop down menu is present in the window but when to your press the arrow there are no values present. I cant find any glaring errors in the code and any clarification would be great.
 List<Dog> potentialMatches = allDogs.findMatch(dogCriteria);
        if (!potentialMatches.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Dog> options = new HashMap<>();
            StringBuilder infoToShow = new StringBuilder("Matches Found! The following dogs meet your criteria: \n");
            for(Dog potentialMatch : potentialMatches){
                infoToShow.append(potentialMatch.getName()).append(" (").append(potentialMatch.getMCNo()).append(") ").append("\n"); //shows the dogs name and microchipnumber next to it(example: Greg (12345678))
            }

            String adopt = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, infoToShow +
                    "\n\nPlease select which of (if any) dog you'd like to adopt: ", appName, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    icon, options.keySet().toArray(), ""); //drop down list in this JOptionPane shows no values, its an issue to do with options.keySet().toArray() but im not sure what.
            if(adopt == null) {
                System.exit(0); }



The behavior you're seeing is the result of when JOptionPane is asked to show a selection dropdown from a zero-length array. In your code, you specify that the select values should be the keys of the options-HashMap. Hovewer, you don't ever add elements to this map, resulting in the map still being empty when you retrieve the keys as an array.
Corrected Code:
        List<Dog> potentialMatches = allDogs.findMatch(dogCriteria);
        if (!potentialMatches.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Dog> options = new HashMap<>();
            StringBuilder infoToShow = new StringBuilder("Matches Found! The following dogs meet your criteria: \n");
            for(Dog potentialMatch : potentialMatches){
                infoToShow.append(potentialMatch.getName()).append(" (").append(potentialMatch.getMCNo()).append(") ").append("\n"); //shows the dogs name and microchipnumber next to it(example: Greg (12345678))
                //populate the options map
                options.put(potentialMatch.getName() + " (" + potentialMatch.getMCNo() + ") ", potentialMatch);
            }

            String adopt = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, infoToShow +
                    "\n\nPlease select which of (if any) dog you'd like to adopt: ", appName, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    icon, options.keySet().toArray(), ""); //drop down list in this JOptionPane shows no values, its an issue to do with options.keySet().toArray() but im not sure what.
            if(adopt == null) {
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }


Don't know how I missed that. Thank you!
